# Metric to compare models?

Tags: r, metric, mape

Using R, I have developed three models:

- linear regression using `lm()`;
- decision tree using `rpart()`;
- k-nearest neighbor using `kknn()`.

I would like to conduct leave-one-out cross-validation tests and compare these models. However, which error metric should I use for better representation? Does mean absolute percentage error (MAPE) or sMAPE (symmetric MAPE) look fine? Please suggest me a metric.

For example, when I conducted leave-one-out CV tests on linear regression (LR) and decision tree (DT) models, the sMAPE error values are 0.16 and 0.20. However, the R-squared values of LR and DT are 0.85 and 0.92 respectively. Where sMAPE computed as `[sum (abs(predicted - actual)/((predicted + actual)/2))] / (number of data points)`. Here DT is pruned regression tree. These R^2 values are computed on full data set. There are a total of 60 data points in the set.

```
Model  R^2   sMAPE
 LR    0.85   0.16
 DT    0.92   0.20
```

Comment: The metric will depend on the purpose of the regression.  Typically, though, because most regressions work by minimizing something (like a sum of squares of residuals or a negative log likelihood), you usually would choose a metric similar to that objective function.  Otherwise your regression probably is inappropriate.

Comment: @kpp Please, feel free to [link your questions](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/13479/how-to-find-r-squared-value-of-k-nearest-neighbor-model-with-the-kknn-method) when they are related to the same problem (unless I am wrong).

Comment: @kkp, this [article](http://www.buseco.monash.edu.au/ebs/pubs/wpapers/2005/wp13-05.pdf) by R. Hyndman and A. Koeller has a comparison of various fit metrics. It might be of use for you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Lots of metric exist and no one is generally the best to use, it depends of your problem, of your data. Often, many metric can be used. I find usefull, to compute both hypothesis test and different metric (RMSE, MAPE ...), and see if they provide similar result. So your conclusions won't be based only on one metric.